# fibres are connected, total space connected $\Rightarrow$ base space is so?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

suppose $G_n$ be the group of $n\times n$ non-singular matrcies with detereminant $>0$,  suppose we have a map $f:G_n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$  such that $A\mapsto Ae_1$, which is surjective, continuous. where $e_1=(1,0,0,\dots,0)$
the fiber corresponding to $e_1$ is homeomorphic to $G_{(n-1)}\times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ which are connected, I want to know $G_n$  is connected?given that $G_{n-1}$ is connected.

Comment: The answer to your _title_ question is yes: the continuous image of a connected space is always connected. But the _body_ question is something else!

Comment: I don't know the definition of a submersion, but if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a quotient map of topological spaces (surjective, continuous, $f^{-1}(V)$ open iff $V\subseteq Y$ is open) and the fibers of $f$ are connected, then $f$ induces a bijection between the connected components of $X$ and those of $Y$. In particular, if $Y$ is connected, then $X$ is.

Comment: Dear miosaki: please edit the question so that the title and the body ask the same question. Currently, we have one answer for each and that is rather confusing.

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: @miosaki, please do eedit the *title* of the question so that it matches what you are asking! Otherwise, it makes it less easy for people to do searches and such things in the future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

N.B: The original question has been completely re-written since this answer was posted. Check the page history to see the original question.

In short: yes! You have a fibre bundle $\pi : T \twoheadrightarrow B$, where $\pi$ is a continuous surjection and both the fibres $\pi^{-1}(b)$ and the total space $T$ are connected. Connectedness is preserved by continuous maps, so if $T$ is connected then $B$ must be connected too.

We can show what the base space is connected as follows:

Assume that the base space $B$ is disconnected. Then there exist open subsets $X,Y \subset B$ such that $X \cup Y = B$ while $X \cap Y = \emptyset$. Since $\pi$ is a continuous surjection it follows $\pi^{-1}(X)$ and $\pi^{-1}(Y)$ are open in $T$ and that $\pi^{-1}(X), \pi^{-1}(Y) \subset T$ such that $\pi^{-1}(X) \cup \pi^{-1}(Y) = T$ and $\pi^{-1}(X) \cap \pi^{-1}(Y) = \emptyset$. It follows that $T$ is also disconnected, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Not all surjective submersions are fiber bundles.

Comment: (For example, pick any locally trivial fiber bundle of manifolds and delete any closed subset in its domain without breaking surjectivity)

Comment: You are answering the question in the title, which is different to that of the body of the question. It would be best if you qualified the initial *yes* to make this explicit :-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Obviously not, but it would have been pedantic of me to ignore the title. However, even ignoring the title, my answer is still valid: "*Connectedness is preserved by continuous maps*". Whether or not $\pi : T \to B$ is a fibre bundle, or simply a continuous surjection, if $T$ is continuous then $B$ is. Nowhere did I discuss the fibres, other than repeating this OP's assumptions. The fibre condition is superfluous.

Comment: My first comment merely referred to the fact that your second sentence starts with «You have a fiber bundle...» and that is not quite correct.

Comment: As I said: ignoring the title would have been pedantic.

Comment: The title does not imply that one has a fiber bundle either, really: «fibers are connected» in no way requires or implies that the map be a fiber map, and thus the hypothesis «the fibers are connected» can very well apply to a surjective submersion which is not a fiber bundle. If it read instead «the fiber is connected» it would suggest a fiber bundle, though.

Comment: Whatever you say. I'm bored now.

Comment: It matters in that there *is* a difference between a surjective submersion and a fiber map, which is important to take into account (and which is somewhat counter-intuitive) —as clearly the OP is starting in the subject, helping him keep things straight *is* valuable. It does not affect me in the least personally, of course, and as this interchange has taken from me only an insignificant amount of energy and attention, I don't see it as a burden and a bore in the same way you seem to see it. In any case, the question has been edited into involving an actual fiber map :-)

Comment: May I suggest that we could better invest our energies in helping answer other questions rather than discussing minor technical details.